# Nlog archive does not work programmatically

Tags: c#, nlog

I am trying to configure nlog programmatically. Everything works file, except the automatic, rolling archiving. My idea:

- Archive when log is bigger than 1 MB
- Keep at most 10 archives
- Use rolling mode for the archives
- Compress the archives

Part of my code:

```
var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
fileTarget.FileName = logFileName;
fileTarget.Layout = pattern;

fileTarget.ArchiveOldFileOnStartup = true;
fileTarget.ArchiveAboveSize = 1000000; // 1 MB
fileTarget.MaxArchiveFiles = 10;
fileTarget.ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Rolling;
fileTarget.ArchiveFileName = logFileName + ".Archive.{##}";
fileTarget.EnableArchiveFileCompression = true;
```

Unfortunately, my log file is growing and growing and it is never archived.
Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what value you have assigned to `logFileName` in your example code?

Comment: I added a `.zip` at the end of the `ArchiveFileName` - and it works now

Comment: You can post your working configuration as answer to your question.